# Show that a set of polynomials form a basis for the polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to show that the set $B=\{1,1-x,1-x^2,...,1-x^n\}$ is a basis for the vector space $V=\{P(x)\in\mathbb{K}[X]|deg(P(X))\leq n\}$.

I know that I need to show that B is a spanning set and a linearly independed set. So here is what I did:
 Let p(x)=$a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n \in V, \alpha_0,\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $p(x)=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x+...+\alpha_nx^n$, and I need to find $\alpha_0,...,\alpha_n$. But here is where I stuck because I get something like $1-x^n=x^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to show that $B$ is linearly independent.

Assume we have the equation:

$a_0+a_1.(1-x)+...+a_n.(1-x^n)= 0$  then we get:

$a_n.x^n+...+a_1.x -(a_0+...+a_n)=0$

Because $(x^n,...,x,1)$ is the basis we must have:

$a_n$=...=$a_1$=$0$  and $a_0+...+a_n$=$0$, hence $a_n=...=a_1=a_0$=$0$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\alpha_0\cdot 1+\alpha_1\cdot (1-x)+\cdots +\alpha_n\cdot(1-x^n)=\alpha_0+\cdots+\alpha_n-\alpha_1x-\cdots -\alpha_n x^n.$$

So, if you consider $a_n=-\alpha_n, \cdots, a_1=-\alpha_1, a_0=\alpha_0+\cdots +\alpha_n$ then you have

$$a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n=\alpha_0\cdot 1+\alpha_1\cdot(1-x)+\cdots +\alpha_n \cdot(1-x^n).$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Let $n>0$ and

$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+....a_nx^n$ be an element of $V$.

then it can be written as

$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k+\sum_{k=1}^n (-a_k)(1-x^k)$

thus $B$ is a spanning set.